# Is there any support in spring-data-cassandra for updating cassandra counter tables?

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I'm using spring-data-cassandra but I can't find a method in CassandraTemplate that deals with counters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for the counter column at this time.  Please create a Jira for the enhancement request and we will schedule it in a future release.

Comment: This is currently not true , `Assignment.CounterAssignment` exists since version `2.0` of datastax driver.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this using `QueryBuilder`. It has special method for this purpose: `QueryBuilder.incr("count_col")`, here `count_col` is column with type `counter`. It produces instance of inner static class `Assignment.CounterAssignment`.

For example your entire update can be built as:

```
Update update = QueryBuilder.update("stats_count_table").
                with(QueryBuilder.incr("count_col")).
                where(eq("key1", key1)).
                and(eq("key2", key2));
```